# Erro: Firebase API initialization failure

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

Estou com o seguinte erro:

> Firebase API initialization failure.

Desta form, toda vez que envio uma notificação através do Firebase, o APP da "crasheia".

## Bundle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
}
```

## MyInstanceIDService:

```
public class MyInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = MyInstanceIDService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.i(TAG, "Token: " + refreshedToken);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // TODO: Send any registration to your app's servers.
    }
}
```

## FireBaseMessagingService

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // Create and show notification
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Também já gerei o `google-services.json`, porém ainda continua o erro. Alguém sabe o motivo pelo qual o Firebase não está inicializando? Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Você já tentou adicionar o Firebase Core `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1` ?

Answer (score 0):

Você tem de colocar o Firebase Core no gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
```

Comment: Se esta resposta foi útil, talvez queira clicar no botão de votar à esquerda dela. Se ela respondeu à sua questão, talvez queira [aceitá-la](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Assim os outros saberão que você foi (minimamente) ajudado. Mais detalhes: [O que eu devo fazer se alguém responder minha pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)